# how do i get itemvalue of <f:selectItem> in my Bean?

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

How to get value from  "itemvalue" attribute of 'f:selectItem itemLabel="Request Posting" itemValue="1" ' in a managed Bean in jsf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF will just set it in the property behind `value` attribute of the `UISelectOne` or `UISelectMany` component wherein you are using this `<f:selectItem>` as child.

E.g.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.someProperty}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Request Posting" itemValue="1" />
    ...
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
```

It'll during the invoke action phase (e.g. in command button action method) just be available as `someProperty`.

```
private String someProperty; // +getter+setter

public void submit() {
    System.out.println(someProperty); // Look, JSF has already set it!
}
```

#### See also:

- [Our `<h:selectOneMenu>` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

Comment: Basically I was using primefaces select one menu i.e ( <p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.someProperty}">)  that 's why i am not getting the value but when i changed to this i.e (<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.someProperty}">) i get the value thanks for your reply sir Balus

Comment: The PrimeFaces one should work either. In the future questions, please try to ask them in SSCCE flavor.

Comment: Ok Sir but kindly make wiki page on on primefaces select one menu

Comment: Just replace `h:` by `p:`.